# Error Number: 1064. Ошибка синтаксиса SQL при выполнении запроса

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Все привет!

**Получаю ошибку**:

> Error Number: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'WHERE id = '5'' at line 15 UPDATE transactions SET
>   type = '4', sum = '1000.00', fee = '50.00', amount = '1200.00', status
>   = '4', sender = 'admin', receiver = 'testuser1', user_comment = '', admin_comment = '', check_notify = '1', notification = '', WHERE id =
>   '5'

**Код запроса:**

```
function edit_transaction($data = array())
{
    if ($data)
    {
        $sql = "
            UPDATE {$this->_db}
            SET
                type = " . $this->db->escape($data['type']) . ",
                                     sum = " . $this->db->escape($data['sum']) . ",
                fee = " . $this->db->escape($data['fee']) . ",
                amount = " . $this->db->escape($data['amount']) . ",
                status = " . $this->db->escape($data['status']) . ",
                sender = " . $this->db->escape($data['sender']) . ",
                receiver = " . $this->db->escape($data['receiver']) . ",
                user_comment = " . $this->db->escape($data['user_comment']) . ",
                admin_comment = " . $this->db->escape($data['admin_comment']) . ",
                check_notify = " . $this->db->escape($data['check_notify']) . ",
                notification = " . $this->db->escape($data['notification']) . ",
            WHERE id = " . $this->db->escape($data['id']) . "
        ";

        $this->db->query($sql);

        if ($this->db->affected_rows())
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

**Вопрос:**

Почему я получаю ошибку?
Проект на CI.

Благодарен за любую помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно данная проблема исходит из синтаксической ошибки, заметил одну

```
 notification = " . $this->db->escape($data['notification']) . ",
            WHERE id = " . $this->db->escape($data['id']) . "
```

лишний знак запятой до `WHERE`, должно быть так

```
 notification = " . $this->db->escape($data['notification']) . "
            WHERE id = " . $this->db->escape($data['id']) . "
```